# Oracle 12 - Improve Insert performance

Tags: oracle, performance, foreign-keys, bulkinsert

We are migrating a legacy project with huge data set (100+ Tables and many of them are 10 million+ records). Few of them are huge (around 100 million).

When we switch the application, we will get only couple of hours to migrate this data to new application which has same tables but slightly different structure (so cannot import or pump).

We are inserting the records as follows:

1. Created a DB Link from source to Destination database
2. DISABLE all Constraints on destination table (and child tables if any)
3. ALTER all indexes as UNUSABLE
4. INSERT /*+ APPEND NOLOGGING PARALLEL*/ INTO destination_table SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */ FROM source_table
5. REBUILD all indexes (REBUILD PARALLEL NOLOGGING and then change to NOPARALLEL and LOGGING)
6. ENABLE all Constraints on destination table (and child tables if any)

It works well but takes longer to finish (avg 5 mins for around 10 million records). Most of the time is spent in STEP 6 and specially for FOREIGN KEY constraints where both Parent and Child are huge.

How can we optimize the insert performance of our database as described above?

Comment: Are you doing Step 6 (enable constraint) in parallel also?

Comment: @btpys We do not enable constraint in parallel explicitly. But are those not done in parallel by default? Do you mean Enable novalidate and then validate the constraint?

Comment: No, I mean altering the session before enabling the constraints: ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DDL PARALLEL 8;

Comment: @btpys Sure will give it a try. Also There are few non-cached sequences which I think can improve some performance.

Comment: Yes that helped. Now we are able to insert around 593 million records in 84 minutes, which is quite acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happy to receive different approaches however we will be refining our approach (as we already have working solution). Being said that this might not "BEST" way for sure but it addresses our concerns in this specific case.

So the steps we finally followed are;

1. Disable all Constraints on Destination Table (and Child tables if any)
2. Disable all Indexes on Destination Table
3. Increase Cache of Sequences if used
4. Perform INSERT (hint APPEND & NOLOGGING) INTO SELECT (hint PARALLEL)
5. Rebuild all Indexes on Destination Table with PARALLEL NOLOGGING
6. Alter Indexes to change to NOPARALLEL & LOGGING
7. Enable all Constraints using NOVALIDATE  (and Child tables if any)
8. ALTER TABLE *TABLE_NAME* PARALLEL
9. Enable all Constraints using VALIDATE
10. ALTER TABLE *TABLE_NAME* NOPARALLEL

Above steps are repeated for all tables in a script which starts with

**ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DDL**

> Tables: **99**
>
> Records: **593,960,688**
>
> Time taken: **01:23:44** Hrs

Comment: Glad you increased the cache size of sequences; the default of `20` is way too small for daily use, and for huge loads like this, caching `100000` may be appropriate.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem, could you please tell more about 4th step? As you, I am disabling constraints and making indexes unusable, also table is altered to nologging mode. After that I am trying to use append_values hint with parallel hint, but it doesn't seem to work. Select is like this: 'Insert /* append_values parallel(table_name,20) */ into table_name values (...) ". Append values hint is working however I don't see any other parallel sessions for this. Can you show your insert statement? In the parent procedure I have enabled parallel dml.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you're looking for performance, you're going to have a problem piping data over a db_link.

Unload the data to flat files, then setup external table/CTAS or SQL Loader to load the data into the new system. It will be *significantly* faster.

[A very small example showing the type of rates I was able to achieve on just a laptop and a VM.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/10/yes-sqlloader-is-faster-at-loading-records/)

TL/DR;

112,000 rows per second via SQL Loader...on a windows laptop.

Comment: your example is definitely interesting but not sure if it works for me. As I mentioned, the table structure is not exactly same. Legacy database for ex. stores dates as varchar, missing relationships, unwanted keys etc. So a table in source and destination databases does not match 100%. Do you have any suggestion if SQL Loader can still be used?

Comment: your example showed moving the data over with a SELECT * FROM ... so apparently diff table structure isn't an issue. Also, if you use external tables, once they're readable with SQL, you can form the INSERT in any order and convert data types as necessary

Comment: also, you should be able to UNLOAD the data with only the fields you need, and again converting types as necessary

Comment: SELECT * FROM was just an example however there are certain transformations to be made like dates stored in string in different formats to be type-casted, few tables to be inserted via joins, added extra constraints and ID columns populated via sequences. However your approach is still interesting and can be faster but then we have to do "something" before importing data so it complies to new structure.

Comment: yeah, do the 'something' as you unload the data out...it's an ETL operation, with the E and T being done with SQL and the L being done with an external table or SQLLDR

Answer (score 0):

If you only get two hours to migrate a huge project, you can do the following:

1. Make the data read-only after step 4 (perhaps using a separate tablespace for the project, then do a `alter tablespace new_stuff read only;` )
2. Let the users into the application.  The users can view the data (possibly slowly until step 5 is done)
3. After step 6 is done, alter the tablespace to be `read write`.

Comment: The moment application is started (after step 4), many background operations will kick-start, which are critical. We can even stop them for a while but that defeats whole idea of limiting downtime to 2 hours. Rest all the release activities can be prepared in advanced, but the data is only thing which we have to hot-transfer exactly in that window.